# How to put advertising in a Maven generated site like GoogleAds

Tags: maven, adsense, apt

I have a Maven generated site, and I would like to include some Google Ads or similar type of publicity in the site.
GoogleAds works with a script tag in the HTML, however when using a simple Maven site with only APT files, I cannot see a way to put the publicity in the files.
Is there a way to include those script tag in order to add publicity to my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put Google publicity inside a Maven generated site you can use the plugin MGAIP.
You just add this as a report

  net.sf.mgaip
  mgaip
  1.1

And then put the googleAds as a poweredBy.
For more information please visit http://mgaip.sourceforge.net

Comment: You can mark you own answer as accepted as well. This is helpful for others who look for unanswered questions.